# RDS java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)

Tags: ssl, amazon-rds

When using aws I have not been able to obtain an SSL connection for RDS MySQL DB instance. All of the jdbc connection was verified such as host,port and name of the DB. With SSLverify=false, the connection succeeded.

I looked at answers that readily available but something is different on AWS RDS.

What is the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I posted the above question because I went through numerous tests to identify the issue. It turns out that this is a unique issue on aws gov cloud.  Connections on gov cloud to RDS with SSL require the use of an intermediate cert. Apparently, certification chains are not supported for this use on gov cloud.

Here is the text from the RDS user guide:

> An SSL/TLS certificate created by Amazon RDS is the trusted root entity and should work in most cases but might fail if your application does not accept certificate chains. If your application does not accept certificate chains, you might need to use an intermediate certificate to connect to your AWS Region. For example, you must use an intermediate certificate to connect to the AWS GovCloud (US) Regions using SSL/TLS.

I found that text tucked away on two specific pages in the document:

MariaDB - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mariadb-ssl-connections.html#MariaDB.Concepts.SSLSupport and

MySQL - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql-ssl-connections.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport

I posted this finding because the issue wasted my time while checking all the well known issues with JDBC connections. In searching for others with a similar problem, this specific problem was not addressed.

I hope that others save some time with this posting and perhaps aws will identify a better way to identify why there could be a problem in making a JDBC connection to those DBs with SSL.